# Draw a distribution diagram!

Tags: code-golf, random

### Challenge

You are given three integers as input - `min_value, max_value, sample_size`, that you can pass to your answer as either array or several parameters.

Your task is to **output a diagram in any convenient format**, that shows the frequency of numbers in the `(min_value, max_value)` range showing up when a random number in the `(min_value, max_value)` range is picked `sample_size` times. The random number sequence should be generated within your answer.

With large ranges and sample sizes, you're free to change the steps your diagram uses, as long as the representation remains accurate.

### Example

With `[1, 5, 10]` as input:

```
o o o x o
x o x x x
x x x x x
1 2 3 4 5
```

With `[1, 100, 15]` as input (in steps of 10, so 00 shows 1-9, 10 shows 10-19, etc.):

```
xx oo oo xx oo xx oo oo oo oo
xx oo oo xx oo xx xx oo oo oo
xx xx oo xx xx xx xx xx xx oo
00 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: I guess we aren't allowed to output tables with a larger height than necessary? For your `[1,5,10]` example, can the height be `10`? So column 4 would look like this (vertically top-to-bottom instead of horizontally left-to-right): `oooooooxxx4`.

Comment: You could do that, as long as it generates a readable output - I don't see why have that restriction.

Comment: Must we always show any zeros in the distribution picked? For example if we use input `[1,5,10]` and happen to pick ten fours is an output showing ten fours acceptable or should we also show we have picked zero threes etc? ("the frequency of numbers in the min_value-max_value range" seems to imply we must show zeros)

Comment: The zeros must be present.

Comment: What's to stop me from selecting a bin of width `b-a`? That's quite a convenient format...

Comment: @Giuseppe Correct me if I got you wrong, but you mean that, for example, for a 10 to 100 range, your diagram would start with 10 instead of 0? If so, yeah, that's valid.

Comment: Giuseppe means that for a range `a...b`, the diagram has a single bin that covers the entire range, resulting in a single bar with height equal to the number of samples.

Comment: Are we allowed to draw the histogram horizontally? Also, do the values have to be chosen uniformly in the range, or is any distribution where all outcomes are possible valid?

Comment: @Mnemonic about the distribution: The [consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10923/31516) is that it doesn't have to be uniform unless OP has specified it.

Comment: @Mnemonic horizontal drawing is allowed, and the distribution does not have to be uniform.

Comment: @Stewie yes, that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: Does the input have to be an array, or can it be separate numbers?

Comment: @LuisMendo It can be separate numbers, too. I'll add that to the challenge text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ṫɓr/;"xẊĠ>ʋ¥G
```

Uses a *very* convenient format:

- Prints the values on the left axis
- Uses `0` as the distribution pixels (like the `x`s) and `1` as the background pixels (like the `o`s)
- Uses as many horizontal spaces between "pixels" as there are characters in the maximum length number in the range (e.g. -23 is length 3, while 23 is length 2).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9qZWxsef//4bmqyZNyLzsieOG6isSgPsqLwqVH////Wzk3LCAxMDMsIDIwXQ)**

Note: If the input did not have to be an array it would be **11 bytes** taking two arguments, `[from, to]` and `sampleSize` with just `r/;"xẊĠ>ʋ¥G`.

---

I think this may be taking the convenient formatting allowance just a little too far for 4 bytes:

[`Ṗ;1K`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzmnWht7///@3NNcxNDAGYgA)

This is using the idea (which should be addressed) put forward by [Giuseppe in the comments](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe) with a single bin identified with `from` and `to` separated by a space, another space representing the axis and and a single `1` representing the height of 100%.

...or even just [`Ṗ1`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzmmG////tzTXMTQwBmIA) for 2 bytes!

Answer (score 10):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>34</s> 32 bytes

```matlab
@(a,b,n)hist(--a+randi(b-a,n,1))
```

Doesn't work on TIO, but works on [Octave-online.net](https://octave-online.net/#cmd=f%3D%40(a%2Cb%2Cn)hist(--a%2Brandi(b-a%2Cn%2C1))).

It creates a histogram (bar chart) looking like this:

[image]

I'd say that counts as "Any convenient format".

If non-zero bins *must* be shown, then this can be solved in 38 bytes:

```matlab
@(a,b,n)hist(--a+randi(b-a,n,1),a+1:b)
```

Comment: I asked for clarification about zero height bins - this fails to show them if they are strictly less than or strictly greater than all non-zero ones (`f(1,5,1)` would show the behaviour for example).

Comment: I feel obliged to point out that that is most certainly *not* a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram), rather it is a [bar chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_chart) (which aren't the same thing, at all).

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing skimming through those wiki pages I don't see what this wouldn't be a histogram. Care to explain why you think it's a bar chart instead?

Comment: @Imus a histogram is a special kind of bar chart. I reckon the point that caird coinheringaahing wants to make is that it only qualifies as a histogram if the bins are large enough to allow estimating the actual distribution of the random variable (which in this case is actually completely flat). For a sample size of only 10 it's not really possible to create a proper histogram.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 36 bytes

```r
function(a,b,n)stem(sample(a:b,n,T))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jUSdJJ0@zuCQ1V6M4MbcgJ1Uj0QooohOiqfk/TcNQx9AAiAw0uf4DAA)

Sigh. A stemplot.

The bane of existence for second year university students taking *Introduction to Statistics for [This Specific Area of Study]* from some professor who doesn't know what they're talking about but still think stemplots are a good idea because it's still in the 14th edition of the textbook they've been using since the 4th edition was published in 1983.

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
≔…·θηθ≔Ｅζ‽θηＥθ№ηι↖←Ｅ⮌θ⮌Ｉι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY09C8IwFEX3/oo3JvAEO7i0k3QSLEjBSRxCjE0gJs1HM/jnY1LU7V3OufdxyTy3TOd8DEHNhpwM12tQSUzMzII4BEkRHO2brzCyhbwRCn7YF3GUVqNvLl6ZuMFSGexagkRQlBY22iRId13O4hn/alcTQm1MIgkfyrOy9bsHFiLZ6jnfWoQDQru/513SHw) Explanation:

```
≔…·θηθ
```

Create an inclusive range of the distribution.

```
≔Ｅζ‽θη
```

Sample the range the desired number of times.

```
Ｅθ№ηι
```

Count and print the number of each of the range in the sample.

```
↖←Ｅ⮌θ⮌Ｉι
```

Print the labels.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 115 bytes

```python
from random import*
a,b,n=input()
r=range(a,b+1)
s=sample(r*n,n)
for v in r:print'%%0%dd'%len(`b`)%v,s.count(v)*'x'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclLCsMgFEDRuatwIn4iJXZSKLiXmGpaIT7laaRdvXV04dzya58M9zEOzImiAz8TU8nYFHF612AjlKsJSdDO/Q5i6mIkqba6VM4gUIEGSY6MtNMIFJ8FIzTO2Mq85@wMILZ9k6zrenvlC5roUvEvH@OhjdFm/QM)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 164 bytes

column-based output.

```python
from random import*
a,b,n=input()
r=range(a,b+1)
s=sample(r*n,n)
d=len(`b`)
while n:n-=1;print' '.join(d*'ox'[s.count(v)>n]for v in r)
for v in r:print'%%0%dd'%d%v,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYvRDoIgGEbveQpuGGDkpO5s9CKtTQ1MnP6wX7R6enLroqvv7Jx98ZOGAKecewwzxRbsPn6OAVNBWtUpMB7imoQkaPb8dGK3By3JYpZ2jpMTWIACSayZHIimayR5DX5yFGo4Gn2J6CFxyssxeBC24OHNb0v5CCsksckr3PuAdKMeKEry5/p3ZKxi1nJm2aZy1upcKV19AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 11, <s>184</s> 168 bytes

```java
(m,M,s)->{int a[]=new int[M],q=M;for(;s>0;q=M)if((q*=Math.random())>m-2){a[q]++;s--;}for(;m<=M;)System.out.printf("%0"+(M+"").length()+"d%s%n",m,"*".repeat(a[m++-1]));}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##XVHRaoMwFH3fV1wChaRGq2VlMGff9jKwL310QjON1c7ENokdo/jtXaLCxiC55CbnnnvuyYldmX8qP@9Fy7SGlDXy9gDQSMNVxQoOO5cCXLumhALbexDUxXSMmsT2ebDbLm2YaQrYgYQE7ljQlGrib28OyLI8kfzLEWdpTi9JGledwrHehrFNSFNhfFkmKTN1oJgsO4EJ2Qp/TW4su@SeF2vfj4exRrzYarL/1oaLoOtNcFaWtsJoESIPpx5CJGi5PJoaEw@VC72QiAqq@Jkzg9ESUZYJz/OjnJB4uMeT@nP/0Vr18xDjvMK6gffGsh@zHBiZrJBBgdf0iUbhODzAfyWtxPOLg25otKGP4V@jVit4FX3LDC/hzX4ARBEcpj7BrNLSkAMIbuqufP71dgLBDJozbRSF0WTR9bZukqm46ZUEZ/qEw@5Y1ExlEy4nrllrPxmj9xBRSzOLHO4/) (NOTE: `String.repeat(int)` is emulated as `repeat(String,int)` for the same byte-count, because Java 11 isn't on TIO yet.)

**Explanation:**

```java
(m,M,s)->{                         // Method with three integer parameters & no return-type
                                   // (`m` = min_value; `M` = max_value; `s` = sample_size)
  int a[]=new int[M],              //  Integer-array, filled with `M` amount of 0s
      q=M;                         //  Temp integer for the random value, set to `M`
  for(;s>0;                        //  Loop as long as `s` isn't 0 yet:
      q=M)                         //    Reset `q` back to `M` after every iteration
    if((q*=Math.random())          //   Pick a random integer in the range [0, `M`)
       >m-2){                      //   If this random integer is larger than `m-2`:
      a[q]++;                      //    Increase the value at that this random index by 1
      s--;}                        //    And decrease `s` by 1
  for(;m<=M;)                      //  Loop in the range [`m`, `M`]
    System.out.printf(             //   Print with trailing new-line
      "%0"+(M+"").length()+"d%s%n",//   and leading zeros if necessary:
      m,                           //    The number
      "*".repeat(a[m++-1]));}      //    appended with "*" repeated the amount of times
                                   //    specified in the random array at index `m-1`
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 52 bytes

```r
function(a,b,n)table(cut(sample(a:b,n,T),a:(b+1)-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCjq/A/rTQvuSQzP08jUSdJJ0@zJDEpJ1UjubREozgxtwDITLQCCuuEaOokWmkkaRtq6hpqav5P0zDUMdUxNNDkgrI0/wMA)

Returns a `table` of frequencies with `names` equal to the half-open intervals selected by `cut`, so `(0,1]`, `(1,2]`, `(2,3]`, and so forth. Makes no effort to select more reasonable binning.

Comment: Wouldn't `function(a,b,n)hist(sample(a:b,n,T))` satisfy the requirements of the question?

Comment: @ngm I guess...I wanted to do a text output since the challenge seemed to intimate that, but you are more than welcome to post it yourself

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <strike>135 bytes</strike>, 117 bytes

```
d=->(m,n,s){p=(m..n);t=(1..s).map{rand(p)};p.map{|h|g=t.count(h);"#{h}-#{'x'*g}#{'o'*(t.map{|e|t.count(e)}.max-g)}"}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
d =-> (m,n,s) {
  p = (m..n)
  t = (1..s).map{rand(p)}
  p.map{ |h|
    g = t.count(h)
    "#{ h }-#{ 'x' * g }#{ 'o' * (t.map{|e| t.count(e) }.max - g) }"
  }
}

puts d.call(1,5,10)
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc27DoIwFIDhV2lwoEU4wODU1MRFnV0JMYdL0iZcmhYUU/rsSHT9/@Ezc/XZtkYkZ9rHQ2yZM@KOVsLQvmnGuBa0BxgYpzmAZdCjdgaHhmrmocVaulWtplDlUeSe699f5YoiHMPIwAu7ubV7XXglTCFLjkUGAFUpwiWMKh4cnPTJwaEPvN/0PFnSQI1dR6PL43YF02IDVndqoilJ//4uEgXT@FTEsy0nJ5JnXw "Ruby – Try It Online") - in case anyone else wanted to test it as I did!

Comment: [L](https://tio.run/##Jc27DoIwFIDhV2lwoEU4wODU1MRFnV0JMYdL0iZcmhYUU/rsSHT9/@Ezc/XZtkYkZ9rHQ2yZM@KOVsLQvmnGuBa0BxgYpzmAZdCjdgaHhmrmocVaulWtplDlUeSe699f5YoiHMPIwAu7ubV7XXglTCFLjkUGAFUpwiWMKh4cnPTJwaEPvN/0PFnSQI1dR6PL43YF02IDVndqoilJ//4uEgXT@FTEsy0nJ5JnXw).

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 85 bytes

```perl
/ \d+/;$d[$`+rand$&-$`+1]++for 1..$';say$"x(length($&)-length),$_,"-"x$d[$_]for$`..$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzRasIwGEbvfYqPLtSWNjURelHKYC@wJ5iiwfzaDpdkSQru5Rfj3M3hwMf5HPlrn970a1WPeIGnQBFn60HqNGE2boktjI15@V5mTxrzGXEiOG8vXn3hcwkRTvlAAdbQM0kb7HSzGZn@YMfGK6NZybPJfdM8zmXXsfUY1A8rbtWVzCVOFStr/tS6ZYe24MXtkR/2OWDHHJQpSfSQYjUIDEMWsZKZ2P6LEH8Qv9bF2ZqQuEn8ve@EFHc)

Produces similar output to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)'s [Charcoal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167543/9365).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 239

I'm sorry about this, but the variables were just named willy-nilly. Anyway, the question said *any convenient format*, so this function returns a sideways graph

```
f=>{x=Math;z=Array;q=_=>x.floor(x.random()*(f[1]-f[0]))+f[0];r=z(f[1]-f[0]).fill(0);z(f[2]).fill``.forEach(_=>r[q()-1]++);u=`${f[1]}`.length;return r.map((e,i)=>`${`${i}`.padEnd(u)}${" x".repeat(e)}`.padEnd(x.max(...r)*2+u," o")).join`\n`}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Japt `-R`, 14 bytes

Takes input in the order max, min, size. Outputs the chart horizontally.

```
õV
öW
Ë+QpVè¥D
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9VYK9lcKyytRcFbopUQ=&input=NSwxLDEwCi1S)

---

### Explanation

```
             :Implicit input of integers U=max_value, V=min_value & W=sample_size
õV           :Range [U,V]
\n           :Reassign to U
öW           :Get an array of W random elements from U
\n           :Reassign to V
Ë            :Map each integer D in U
 +           :  Append
  Q          :  Quotation mark
   p         :  Repeat
    Vè       :   Count the elements in V
      ¥D     :    That equal D
             :Implicitly join with newlines and output.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 19 bytes

```
JmOK}FPQeQVK,N*/JNd
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JmOK%7DFPQeQVK%2CN%2A%2FJNd&input=1%2C%205%2C%2010&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
JmOK}FPQeQVK,N*/JNd
   K}FPQ             Get the inclusive range between the first two inputs as K.
JmO     eQ           Get <last input> random elements as J.
          VK         For each value in the range...
            ,N       ... output a list of the value...
              */JNd  ... and spaces equal to the count in J.
```